# Get response of axios from one js file to another js file

Tags: node.js, axios

I have this axios get request

**getData.js**

```
const int_postData = ({
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
});
axios.post(token_url, int_postData, {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(process.env.int_client_id + ':' + process.env.int_client_secret).toString('base64'),
        "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
})
.then((res) => {
   axios.post(get_data_url, int_personData, {
     //responseType: 'arraybuffer',
     headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + int_access_token
     }
  })
  .then((res) => {
   console.log(res.data)
  })
})
```

**App.js**

Here I need to get the response from getData.js and do display the response.

Comment: Do you want to execute a http request immediately in `getData.js` only once and export the given result back to `app.js` for this reason top level await and ESM would be a must.

Answer (score -1):

- You need to move your all `getData.js` code into a function.
- To make that function call synchronous you have to use either `Promise` or `async/await`.
- Finally to use it export that function using `module.exports` and import it using `require()`.

```js
/* file:getData.js */

//....

async function getData(int_personData) {
  const int_postData = {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  }

  const token_resp = await axios.post(token_url, int_postData, {
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        'Basic ' +
        Buffer.from(process.env.int_client_id + ':' + process.env.int_client_secret).toString(
          'base64'
        ),
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
  })

  const data_url_resp = await axios.post(get_data_url, int_personData, {
    //responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + int_access_token,
    },
  })

  return data_url_resp.data
}

module.exports = getData
// export default getData
```

```js
/* file:App.js */
const getData = require('./getData')
// import getData from './getData.js' 

// now you can call `getData` function here

getData(int_personData)
  .then((resData) => {
    console.log(resData)
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
```

Comment: I do get this [AsyncFunction: getData] when I run it from App.js

Comment: you need to call like this `getData( ... ).then(...)`. I have updated my answer with full code at the end, check it out.

Comment: When doing this way getting this error int_personData is not defined